# AWK: Quick way to insert target words after a source term

Tags: awk, files

I'm not familiar with awk. For inserting a single target term after a source term in 198058 random lines I have this code here

```
awk -i inplace '(NR==FNR){a[$1];next}
    (FNR in a) && gsub(/\<Source Term\>/,"& Target Term")
     1
    ' <(shuf -n 198058 -i 1-$(wc -l < file)) file
```

The `file` contains lines of sentences like these

```
David has to eat his vegetables .
This weather is very cold .
Can you please stop this music ? This is terrible music .
The teddy bear is very plushy .
I must be going !
```

For example, if I want to insert the word "Wetter" after "weather", a certain line will look like this

```
This weather Wetter is very cold .
```

How can I rewrite the code, so I just have to include two different files which contain a list of source terms and target terms?

Assuming the file of source terms is called `sourceterms` and the file of target terms is called `targetterms`.

If `sourceterms` contain a list of these terms

```
vegetables
weather
terrible
plushy
going
```

and `targetterms` contain these terms

```
Gemüse
Wetter
schreckliche
flauschig
gehen
```

I want my code to check in each line of `file` if it contains a source term and inserts the target term after it so my `file` will look like this:

```
David has to eat his vegetables Gemüse .
This weather Wetter is very cold .
Can you please stop this music ? This is terrible schreckliche music .
The teddy bear is very plushy flauschig.
I must be going gehen!
```

Is it possible to rewrite this code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk (which the OP is using) for ARGIND and word boundaries:

```
$ cat tst.awk
ARGIND == 1 { olds[FNR] = "\\<" $1 "\\>"; next }
ARGIND == 2 { map[olds[FNR]] = "& " $1; next }
{
    for ( old in map ) {
        new = map[old]
        gsub(old,new)
    }
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk sourceterms targetterms file
David has to eat his vegetables Gemüse .
This weather Wetter is very cold .
Can you please stop this music ? This is terrible schreckliche music .
The teddy bear is very plushy flauschig .
I must be going gehen !
```

The above assumes your sources don't contain any regexp metachars and your replacement text doesn't contain a `&` backreference metachar. It also assumes that if the same word appears in both source and target you don't care what order the substitutions occur.