# AWK: Insert in random selected lines target terms after source terms from a dictionary

Tags: awk, files

Note: I have already asked a similar question in [AWK: Quick way to insert target words after a source term](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/688449/awk-quick-way-to-insert-target-words-after-a-source-term/688458#688458) and I am at the beginner level of AWK.

This question considers the insertion of multiple target terms after source terms in a number of random selected lines.

With this AWK code snippet

```
awk '(NR==FNR){a[$1];next}
    FNR in a { gsub(/\<source term\>/,"& target term") }
     1
    ' <(shuf -n 5 -i 1-$(wc -l < file)) file
```

I want to insert a `target term` after the `source term` in 5 random lines of the `file`.

For example: I have a bilingual dictionary `dict` which contains the source terms on the left and the target terms on the right like

```
apple     : Apfel
banana    : Banane
raspberry : Himbeere
```

My `file` consists of these lines:

```
I love the Raspberry Pi.
The monkey loves eating a banana.
Who wants an apple pi?
Apple pen... pineapple pen... pen-pineapple-apple-pen!
The banana is tasty and healthy.
An apple a day keeps the doctor away.
Which fruit is tastes better: raspberry or strawberry?
```

Assuming for the first word `apple` the random lines 1, 3, 5, 4, 7 are selected. The output with the word apple will be like this:

```
I love the Raspberry Pi.
The monkey loves eating a banana.
Who wants an apple Apfel pi?
Apple Apfel pen... pineapple pen... pen-pineapple-apple-pen!
The banana is tasty and healthy.
An apple a day keeps the doctor away.
Which fruit is tastes better: raspberry or strawberry?
```

then another 5 random lines; 3, 3, 5, 6, 7; for the word `banana` will be selected:

```
I love the Raspberry Pi .
The monkey loves eating a banana .
Who wants an apple Apfel pi ?
Apple Apfel pen... pineapple pen... pen-pineapple-apple-pen!
The banana Banane is tasty and healthy .
An apple a day keeps the doctor away .
Which fruit is tastes better: raspberry or strawberry?
```

And the same goes on with all the other entries in `dict` until the last entry is matched.

I want to choose 5 random lines. If these lines have a whole source term like `apple` I only want to match `Apfel` to `apple` as whole word (terms like "pineapple" will be ignored). If a line contains a source term twice, like `apple`, than I want to insert the target term after it as well. Matches should be case-insensitive, so I can also match source terms like `apple` and `Apple`.

My question: How can I rewrite the code snippet above, so I can use a dictionary `dict`, which selects *random* lines in `file` and inserts target terms behind the source terms?

Comment: You should start more simple. Do you know how to do this without the randomization?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, but next time please edit the question instead of deleting and reposting.

Comment: @aviro I no idea how to do this without randomization in AWK.

Comment: So why don't you start step by step? First do it without randomization, and then continue. You're trying to build a second floor in your building without even having a first floor. Also, please try first to do this yourself (without randomization), and tell us where you got stuck. You already got an answer to an earlier similar question. Did you understand the answer? Did you try to learn what exactly it's doing? If you really understand it, try to "expand" to your current need (again, without randomization). If you didn't under the previous answer, ask for clarification so you could learn.

Comment: @RamónWilhelm regarding [I no idea how to do this without randomization in AWK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/688689/awk-insert-in-random-selected-lines-target-terms-after-source-terms-from-a-dict#comment1302181_688689) - that's what my answer to your previous question does, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/688458/133219. That would be a much better starting point than the code currently in your question.

Comment: Your first expected output where `Apple` becomes `Apple Apfel` should include `pen-pineapple-apple Apfel-pen` instead of `pen-pineapple-apple-pen` since `apple` appears as a full word in `pen-pineapple-apple-pen`. If that's not what you wanted then your original script wouldn't have worked as it's using word boundaries and then we'd need some definition from you of a "word" that's different from "made of word-constituent characters" as we've been assuming. Ask a new **concise** question just about how to do matching on non-standard "word"s if you need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to select 5 line numbers at random from an input file using awk (and wc for the first pass to just count line numbers):

```
$ awk -v numLines="$(wc -l < file)" 'BEGIN{srand(); for (i=1; i<=5; i++) print int(1+rand()*numLines)}'
7
2
88
13
18
```

Now all you have to do is take [my previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/688458/133219) and for every "old" string being read in the `ARGIND==1` block generate 5 line numbers as shown above, populate an array that maps the generated line numbers to the old strings associated with each line number, and when reading the final input file check if the current line number is in the array and if so loop through the "old"s stored in the array for that line number, doing the `gsub()` shown from my previous answer.

Using GNU awk for `ARGIND`, `IGNORECASE`, word boundaries, arrays of arrays and `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v numLines=$(wc -l < file) '
    BEGIN {
        FS = "\\s*:\\s*"
        IGNORECASE = 1
        srand()
    }
    ARGIND == 1 {
        old = "\\<" $1 "\\>"
        new = "& " $2
        for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {
            lineNr = int(1+rand()*numLines)
            map[lineNr][old] = new
        }
        next
    }
    FNR in map {
        for ( old in map[FNR] ) {
            new = map[FNR][old]
            gsub(old,new)
        }
    }
    { print }
' dict file
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
I love the Raspberry Pi.
The monkey loves eating a banana Banane.
Who wants an apple Apfel pi?
Apple Apfel pen... pineapple pen... pen-pineapple-apple Apfel-pen!
The banana Banane is tasty and healthy.
An apple a day keeps the doctor away.
Which fruit is tastes better: raspberry Himbeere or strawberry?
```

Comment: I've tried this script, but the file wasn't edited. For some reason, the `-i inplace` is refused.

Comment: I'm not using `-i inplace` in my script and you haven't mentioned that in your question but if you want to use that you'll have to get a version of GNU awk that supports it. We already know you're using GNU awk so you must be on a very old pre-inplace version of it. Personally I wouldn't use `-i inplace` as it'll just complicate things because then you'd need to rewrite BOTH input files. Just do `awk '...' dict file > tmp && mv tmp file` if you really want to overwrite `file` with  the output.

Comment: I already did `awk '...' dict file > tmp && mv tmp file`, but nothing has changed.

Comment: That's a different problem to "`-i inplace` is refused". Then you're doing something wrong as the script in my answer WILL produce output that's different from the input if some the lines that contain "apple", for example, occur on some of the random line numbers generated. idk what you're doing wrong though because I can't see your code. I just updated my answer to show my script running against the sample input you provided and producing output that's different from the input.

Comment: Maybe you have a file that's pretty long and none of the 5 line numbers generated for each of the "old" strings in `dict` actually have those strings on any of those 5 line numbers associated with each string? That's the only thing that comes to mind that would cause the output to be unchanged. Do you see changes given the input in your question and it's some other input it "fails" with?

Comment: It's nothing to do with the problem we're discussing here in the comments but I just noticed you said `Matches should be case-insensitive` so I updated my script to set `IGNORECASE = 1` then re-ran it.

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed with extended regex mode (-E) and the (/e) modifier of the s/// command:

```
n=$(< file wc -l)
sed -E '/\n/ba
  s#^(\S+)\s*:\s*(\S+)$#s/\\<\1\\>/\& \2/Ig#;h'"
  s/.*/shuf -n 5 -i '1-$n'/e;G
  :a
  s/^([0-9]+)(\n.*\n(.*))/\1 \3\2/
  /\n.*\n/!s/\n/ /
  P;D
" dict | sed -f /dev/stdin file
```

---

- generate the GNU sed commands from the contents of the duct file.
- store the command in hold.
- roll the dice and generate 5 random numbers in in the range of line length of input file.
- stick the hold onto pattern and generate sed commands to run on these particular lines only.
- apply these commands generated on the input file.

Comment: I was curious what the first sed script would output so I tried it and got an apparently infinite stream of 4 `<number> s/\<apple\>/& Apfel/Ig` lines (always just `apple`, no other substitution) and a number on a line of it's own. I'm using `sed (GNU sed) 4.4` in bash on cygwin. But then when I piped it to  the 2nd sed it did actually terminate and made changes for other fruits too so it seems like the combination actually worked. Could you [edit] your answer to explain what's going on with that interaction between the 2 scripts?

Comment: This behavior was not observed at my end. The first sed terminates after generating 5 * 3 = 15 sed substitution commands

Comment: Well, that's weird, I don't get that behavior today either but I tried it multiple times yesterday just to make sure of what I was seeing. Beats me - magic...